# How can I pass by reference in C++?

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

I need to iterate through a vector of objects, and change a variable of theirs. However, when I do so, C++ gives me the following errors:

`void Projectile::setX(float &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'float' to 'float &'`

`initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue`

The way I try to do this is in this for loop:

```
for (Projectile p : activeProjectiles) {
        if (p.isLeftPublic) {
            float g = p.getX();
            p.setX(g - (60));
        }
        else if (!p.isLeftPublic) {
            float g = p.getX();
            p.setX(g - (60));
        }
    }
```

GetX and SetX functions look like this:

```
float Projectile::getX() {
    return x;
}

void Projectile::setX(float &_x) {
    this->x = _x;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is no reason to pass by reference in `Projectile::setX()`

Comment: You can remove `this->` notation since the parameter and data member have different names.  Access the data member directly:  `x = _x;`

Comment: Personally I would remove the fiddly little `_` from `_x` as `this->x = x;` is unambiguous and expressive.

Comment: And `getX` should be a `const` function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, there is really no reason to pass a `float` by reference into this function. It's tiny already.

If you really want to, though, it should be a `const float&`, because you're not modifying it.

Indeed, it *must* be `const float&` if you're going to bind a temporary to it, as you do here.

---

***tl;dr:*** `g - (60)` is not a variable

---

Then you need to fix your loop, which currently doesn't affect `activeProjectiles` at all:

```
for (Projectile& p : activeProjectiles) {
//             ^ important!
```

Answer (score 0):

Source of the problem is that you iterate by value, so you try to modify copy in the loop. It should be instead:

```
for (Projectile &p : activeProjectiles) {
```

you do not need reference in `void Projectile::setX(float &)` at all. Looks like you heard that to fix your issue you need reference somewhere and you found random place to put it. You are barking on the wrong tree.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the only reason to use a non-`const` reference is when you intend to change the referenced object. Naturally, such a thing should never occur in a setter function. It would be a big surprise if a call like `setX(my_var);` actually modified `my_var`, wouldn't it?

The best solution is to just pass the `float` by value.

You could get the reference to work if you make it `const`, because then it would comply with C++ language rules, which otherwise prevent you from binding a reference to an unnamed temporary object like the one resulting from `g - (60)`; however, that would achieve nothing and just look strange. `const` references are normally used for performance when you pass "big" objects. A `float` is not a "big" object.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the function with a mathematical expression, which would work if your function was not by reference. g-60 is not a variable, so how would you reference it? You need some sort of variable or object that has an **address** in order to pass it by reference. Consider doing g -= 60 first, then passing g into setx, or like mentioned above use const float&